# How to install multiple instances of tomcat in ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: tomcat7, ubuntu-14.04

I would like to install multiple instances of tomcat-7 in my ubuntu 14.04 machine.

is it possible to do without any port conflicts?

If yes can anybody suggest me the best approach.

Thanks & Regards.

Answer (score 0):

You can run multiple instances of Tomcat on same host provided they are listening on different ports. Please change the ports in the TOMCAT_HOME/conf/server.xml of the tomcat servers.

The default ports configured in the file are is 8080, 8005, 8009 and 8443. Change the ports to different values per installation. I prefer a strategy to offset the ports by 10 for second installation i have. You can choose a strategy you find fits well to your requirements.

Note: make sure no other service is listening on the port you set in the file.

Comment: in ubuntu same installation of tomcat won't be installed unless we delete the previous one. how should i install second instance now?

Comment: Please refer to the below mentioned link for details:

Comment: https://madurad.wordpress.com/2014/07/17/installing-and-configuring-multiple-tomcat-server-instances/